# Is "they use sbt, an IDE, and other tools as their interface to the compiler" contrary to "therefore they may not even have scalac installed"?

Tags: scala, sbt

https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/compiler-options/index.html says

> Scala compiler scalac offers various compiler options, also referred to as compiler flags, to change how to compile your program.
>
> Nowadays, most people are not running `scalac` from the command line. Instead, they use sbt, an IDE, and other tools as their interface to the compiler. Therefore they may not even have `scalac` installed, and won’t think to do `man scalac`.

Does "the compiler" refer to `scalac`?

If yes, is "they use sbt, an IDE, and other tools as their interface to the compiler"    contrary to "therefore they may not even have `scalac` installed"?

Does `sbt` rely on `scalac`?

Thanks.

Comment: sbt will download the compiler needed into `${HOME}/.ivy`. You can think of it as venv.

Comment: What is the compiler that sbt rely on?

Comment: scalac or dotty, depending on the configuration of your project

Comment: So sbt installs the compiler, why does it say that "therefore they may not even have scalac installed"?

Comment: I think they meant "*system wide*, *manual* installation", in contrast to the automatic, home directory installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala compiler can be accessed programmatically via an API packaged by `scala-compiler.jar` dependency, hence tools such as IDEs and SBT can implement their own client frontends over this API to drive compiler functionality. `scalac` is just a bash script that executes [`scala.tools.nsc.MainClass`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/a5aeb418f4b2f842cf068899c1323f41ccf93f9d/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/Main.scala#L19) class from `scala-compiler.jar`.

---

> Does `sbt` rely on `scalac`?

No, sbt uses compiler API directly. One of the key concepts to understand regarding sbt is that the build definition is itself Scala code, either vanilla or DSL, but Scala nevertheless. The [version](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Configuring-Scala.html#sbt%E2%80%99s+Scala+version) of Scala used to compile the build definition is [separate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49010993/5205022) from the version of Scala used to compile project proper. The build definition source code in `build.sbt` and `project/*.scala` will be compiled using Scala version specified indirectly via `sbt.version=1.2.8` setting in `project/build.properties`, whilst project source code proper in `src/main/scala/*` will be compiled using Scala version specified directly via `scalaVersion := "2.13.1"` setting in `build.sbt`. Note how they can indeed differ. Think of the build definition as simply another [Scala app](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Organizing-Build.html#sbt+is+recursive) which uses sbt API for its implementation.

Comment: Thanks. What compiler does sbt rely on?

Comment: Do you mean sbt (and IDE such as IntelliJ) doesn't use `scalac`?

Comment: Why would a tool written in Scala or Java use the wrapper script around the compiler API when they can use the compiler API?

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thanks. In case of Java, do  Java IDEs and build tools also work in similar way as Scala's?  Do they rely on `javac` and `java` commands?

Comment: @JörgWMittag https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60697141/do-java-ides-and-build-tools-rely-on-javac-and-java-commands