# Which version of sbt is compatible with scala 2.13.4

Tags: scala, sbt

I have scala 2.13.8 and sbt 1.5.8 installed using brew command But i am using scala 2.13.4 in intellij for my project and sbt 1.4.4.I have also installed scala plugin But my project gives unable to fetch project structure from sbt.
And thus I'm not able to install any of the dependencies.

Comment: Sbt version is independent from scala version you'd like to use for your project. Your problem is not versions. Something is wrong with you sbt file. Please update your question with `build.sbt` file content

Comment: Also in IntelliJ you have to click on the top error message on the build output to get more details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the relationship of the versions of scala when I use sbt to build a scala project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49000201/whats-the-relationship-of-the-versions-of-scala-when-i-use-sbt-to-build-a-scala)