# Does SBT support all versions of scala?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to understand the SBT + Scala version compatibility

I am looking at https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Configuring-Scala.html where it mentions that sbt automatically obtains the scala version required by the project, however I do not see any concrete literature claiming that all versions of SBT works across all versions of scala.

If someone can please guide me to similar documentation somewhere. Tried https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Configuring-Scala.html, also went through [What's the relationship of the versions of scala when I use sbt to build a scala project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49000201/whats-the-relationship-of-the-versions-of-scala-when-i-use-sbt-to-build-a-scala)

Comment: Do you have any reason to think it may not work? Are you worries about some specific version?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75531849/why-does-sbt-show-a-different-scalaversion-than-my-system